# Deploy Python Flask on IIS 10 - post route failure

Tags: python, flask, iis, wfastcgi

I have a Flask App with Python 3.9 (I used different versions of Python same problem) my iis server Version is 10.

In my App I have 4 different post routes. 3 of them work like a charm. When I call the fourth one which is almost the same like the other 3, I get a 500 error and I have no idea why. When I start the Flask server without iis, every post route work. I did every tutorial here or on different websites but my problem is still there.
Does anybody know this problem or have a solution why one of the methods won't work?

Comment: Check error logs, definitely something must be over there.

Comment: According to your description, it is impossible to know the problem cause by, you need to post your error message.

Comment: How did you set up Python on IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler HttpPlatformHandler is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is an output of my log file:

2021-05-06 09:43:27.854195: wfastcgi.py will restart when files in C:\masterarbeit\flask\ are changed: .*((.py)|(.config))$
2021-05-06 09:43:27.869792: wfastcgi.py 3.0.0 initialized
2021-05-06 09:43:28.479183: wfastcgi.py exiting because upload\Teacup.py has changed, matching .*((.py)|(.config))$
2021-05-06 09:43:28.510435: Running on_exit tasks

The error come when i call an ajax script. this script works when i start the flask server without iis. The ajax script calls a python method which returns a json string.
The other ajax scripts which are similar work like a charm.

UPDATE: when i change the json return e.g. to a single char instead of the json string, it works.
The error come in this line:
fig = go.Figure()

Comment: Sadly not. It depends on the imports.but I don't know why fastcgi has problems with some imports.